# vxworks compile success but "ld" command fail

Tags: compilation, vxworks

I use IDE WindRiver Workbench to compile DKM project! It compiles successfully. But "ld" command fails complaining like:

```
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol __GOTT_BASE__.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol __GOTT_INDEX__.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Assert.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Stoul.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Getpctype.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Stderr.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Getptoupper.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Getptolower.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Stod.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Flt.
Warning: module 0x1e2f0b8 holds reference to undefined symbol _Stdout.
ld(): error loading file (errno = 0xe0005).
```

Comment: Is there a way to figure out from what function these undefined symbols are called?

Answer (score 6):

You get these errors because the mentioned symbols cannot be resolved in the system symbol table.

From the VxWorks Kernel Programmer's Guide 6.8, ch. 16.3.7 (very useful chapter for loading issues)

> The system symbol table is used to store the names and addresses of functions and variables already installed in the system. This has the side effect that once symbols are installed in the
>   system symbol table, they are available for future linking by any module that is
>   loaded. Moreover, when attempting to resolve undefined symbols in a module,
>   the loader uses all global symbols compiled into the target image, as well as all
>   global symbols of previously loaded modules.

Tips:

- Check that the order in which you are loading modules is correct. Loading will fail on that DKM if you are loading the symbols afterwards in another DKM.

> [...] dependencies between modules must be taken into account when
>   modules are loaded to ensure that references can be resolved for each new module,
>   using either code compiled into the VxWorks image or modules that have already
>   been loaded into the system.
>   Failure to do so results in incompletely resolved code [...]

- "lkup" command is useful to find what symbols have been previously loaded

Comment: Can you provide any insight in relation to mixing C/C++?  I had one C module that used "SemLib.h" and it worked fine.  I then changed it to C++ as a wrapper around the lib functions, and got S_loadLib_UNDEFINED_REFERENCES error.  I've tried using extern "C" in places and on the library functions, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hmmm.. sounds like you should open a new question for this ;)